# Как отловить подключение флешки?

Tags: windows, winapi, delphi-7, usb

Помогите, пожалуйста, с рабочим примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотри разбирайся, сложного ничего нет

```
    unit usb_utils;

//http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/tipsindex.php

interface

uses 
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Forms;

type

  PDevBroadcastHdr  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR; 
  DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record 
    dbch_size: DWORD; 
    dbch_devicetype: DWORD; 
    dbch_reserved: DWORD; 
  end;

  PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE; 
  DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE = record 
    dbcc_size: DWORD; 
    dbcc_devicetype: DWORD; 
    dbcc_reserved: DWORD; 
    dbcc_classguid: TGUID; 
    dbcc_name: short; 
  end;

const 
  GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE: TGUID = '{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}'; 
  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL          = $8000;          // system detected a new device 
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE   = $8004;          // device is gone 
  DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = $00000005;      // device interface class

type

  TComponentUSB = class(TComponent) 
  private 
    FWindowHandle: HWND; 
    FOnUSBArrival: TNotifyEvent; 
    FOnUSBRemove: TNotifyEvent; 
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); 
    function USBRegister: Boolean; 
  protected 
    procedure WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage); dynamic; 
  public 
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; 
    destructor Destroy; override; 
  published 
    property OnUSBArrival: TNotifyEvent read FOnUSBArrival write FOnUSBArrival; 
    property OnUSBRemove: TNotifyEvent read FOnUSBRemove write FOnUSBRemove; 
  end;

implementation

constructor TComponentUSB.Create(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin 
  inherited Create(AOwner); 
  FWindowHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc); 
  USBRegister; 
end;

destructor TComponentUSB.Destroy; 
begin 
  DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle); 
  inherited Destroy; 
end;

procedure TComponentUSB.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); 
begin 
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE) then  
  begin 
    try 
      WMDeviceChange(Msg); 
    except 
      Application.HandleException(Self); 
    end; 
  end 
  else 
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWindowHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam); 
end;

procedure TComponentUSB.WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage); 
var 
  devType: Integer; 
  Datos: PDevBroadcastHdr; 
begin 
  if (Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) or (Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE) then  
  begin 
    Datos := PDevBroadcastHdr(Msg.lParam); 
    devType := Datos^.dbch_devicetype; 
    if devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE then  
    begin // USB Device 
      if Msg.wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then  
      begin 
        if Assigned(FOnUSBArrival) then 
          FOnUSBArrival(Self); 
      end  
      else  
      begin 
        if Assigned(FOnUSBRemove) then 
          FOnUSBRemove(Self); 
      end; 
    end; 
  end; 
end;

function TComponentUSB.USBRegister: Boolean; 
var 
  dbi: DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE; 
  Size: Integer; 
  r: Pointer; 
begin 
  Result := False; 
  Size := SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE); 
  ZeroMemory(@dbi, Size); 
  dbi.dbcc_size := Size; 
  dbi.dbcc_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE; 
  dbi.dbcc_reserved := 0; 
  dbi.dbcc_classguid  := GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE; 
  dbi.dbcc_name := 0;

  r := RegisterDeviceNotification(FWindowHandle, @dbi, 
    DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE 
    ); 
  if Assigned(r) then Result := True; 
end;

end.
```